# CSS not loading on Instructure Canvas App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Having problems getting the CSS to load on on the [Instructure canvas Learning management](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms) system. How can I fix this?

See [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4r1tnz5lnmctbx/Screenshot%202014-08-19%2020.13.46.png).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.  Use rake canvas:compile_assets to fix the css issues.

[See reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/canvas-lms-users/Nd1v3n906QI)